# diffrence between "<" less than operator and "<=" operator when comparing large numbers using pow(x,y)

Tags: java, types, operators

when i tried comparing the number 9223372036854775807 with Math.pow(2,63) it gave the wrong answer. Here is the code

```
long s = (long) (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1) ;
if ((s < Math.pow(2, 63)) && (s >= -Math.pow(2, 63)))
            System.out.println("* long");
```

this doesnt print anything whereas when i do this it does

```
long s = (long) (Math.pow(2, 63) - 1) ;
if ((s <= Math.pow(2, 63)) && (s >= -Math.pow(2, 63)))
            System.out.println("* long");
```

the actual program was this...

```
package practice;

import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Ques2ofHR_database {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i;
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = in.nextInt();
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {

        long s =0;
    try {
            s = in.nextLong();

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println(in.next() + " can't be fitted anywhere.");

            continue;
        }


    System.out.println(s + " can be fitted in:");
        if ((s < Math.pow(2, 7)) && (s >= -Math.pow(2, 7)))
            System.out.println("* byte");

        if ((s < Math.pow(2, 15)) && (s >= -Math.pow(2, 15)))
            System.out.println("* short");

        if ((s < Math.pow(2, 31)) && (s >= -Math.pow(2, 31)))
            System.out.println("* int");

        if ((s <= Math.pow(2, 63)) && (s >= -Math.pow(2, 63)))
            System.out.println("* long");

    }

    }

}
```

this program actually finds out all the datatypes which can store the given number(among byte,short,int and long)

and thankx in advance...

Comment: Loss of precision [after 52 bits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format): `Math.pow(2, 63) - 1 == Math.pow(2, 63)` is true

Answer (score 1):

The `Long.MAX_VALUE` requires 64 bits in order to fit inside a long variable.

`Math.pow(2,63)` returns a double. A double uses the same number of bits (64) to approximate much larger floating point numbers (some of the bits are used by the exponent), so `Math.pow(2,63)` can't be equal to `Long.MAX_VALUE`, since `Long.MAX_VALUE` can't be accurately represented by a double variable.

EDIT :

Actually, `Math.pow(2, 63)` can be represented accurately in a double variable, since it's a power of 2 with a relatively small exponent. However, when you subtract 1 from it, you get a number that can't be represented accurately in a double variable.

Comment: But then how does it give the answer when i replace "<" with "<=" . Since we know that pow(2,63) is not equal to ' s ' how does it matter whether its less than ( < )  or  less than  equal to ( <=) operator.

Comment: @user4885727 When you compare a long to a double, the long is converted to a double. In your case, since `9223372036854775807` can't be accurately represented as a double, it is converted to the nearest double value, which apparently is equal to `Math.pow(2, 63)`.